# U.S. and international legality of the concept of "controlled digital lending"

Tags: copyright, intellectual-property, internet

In light of the ongoing court case [Hachette Book Group, Inc. v. Internet Archive](https://www.publishersweekly.com/pw/by-topic/industry-news/libraries/article/89868-supporters-opponents-weigh-in-on-internet-archive-copyright-battle.html) about the concept of so-called "Controlled Digital Lending" (CDL) by libraries and whether this is copyright infringement, some questions naturally arise.

Controlled digital lending, as far as I understand it, is the lending of a copyrighted work by a library to a user digitally over the internet, in the form of an encrypted eBook through encryption and DRM software such as [Adobe Digital Editions](https://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions.html).

#### Questions

1. Does the concept of "controlled digital lending" exist in any country outside of the United States? If so, how is it allowed in those countries? Is it perhaps covered by a fair use/fair dealing exception?
2. How do physical libraries distribute physical books without violating copyright? Answers pertaining to either the U.S. or other countries are appreciated.
3. It looks like the publishers are primarily targeting the Internet Archive in this case. If the Internet Archive does not succeed in this court case, what would be the implications for existing CDL by libraries in the United States, such as [OverDrive](https://www.overdrive.com/)?

Comment: You understand that lending a physical book does not involve copying?

Comment: The question, then, is whether controlled digital lending should be considered a "copy".  You could argue that it is, because the bits are present on your computer (for you to read it) while also still being present on the server.  You could argue that it is not, because the total number of people able to use the item simultaneously does not change.  The court will decide which argument they like better.

Comment: For (3), I think a lot of those services operate with the permission of the publishers, who probably receive some sort of payment.  So they would be unaffected. The unique aspect of Internet Archive is that they claimed they could distribute the book digitally without needing any permission, based solely on the fact that they possess a legal physical copy of it.